# Express TypeScript route properties

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to create a route in Express using TypeScript, and so I, as usual, set the arguments of `createUser` function to `req`: `Request`, `res`: `Response` and `next`: `NextFunction`, from `@types/express`, obviously. It worked every time, but this time it shows an error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): Router', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
      Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
        Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>' is missing the following properties from type 'Request': cache, credentials, destination, integrity, and 15 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): Router', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
      Type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(path: PathParams, subApplication: Application): Router', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application'.
      Type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 61 more.
```

How to fix that?
Here's some code of the app:

```
protected setupRoutes(): void {
    this.router.post("/", this.createUser);
  }

  // Routes:
  private async createUser(req: Request, res: Response, next): Promise<any> {
    try {
      res.status(200).send("Hi!");
    } catch (err) {
      return next({
        status: err.status,
        message: err.message,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: As a side note, if you ever plan on using `this` inside `createUser` you better set the listener to `this.createUser.bind(this)` instead of `this.createUser`.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks! I forgot. :>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am surprised this worked for you at all. Express has it's own types available for the request and the response that extend the base types you are using.

For instance, here is the [type definition of the express request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts):

```
interface Request<P = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
```

Try using those types:

```
import express from 'express';


const handleMyRequest = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  // Whatever
}
```

Comment: I've used those, but forgot to import from Express types. Now it works fine. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Cholewka Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I used `express.Request` and `express.Response` to solve this problem

```
import { IUserDTO } from "../entities/User";
import { RegisterUserUseCases } from "./registerUserUseCases"
import express from 'express'

class RegisterUserController {
    constructor(private useCase:RegisterUserUseCases){}

    async handle(req: express.Request,res: express.Response):Promise<express.Response> {

        const { email, name, password, phone } : IUserDTO | any = req.body;

        await this.useCase.execute({
            email,
            name,
            password,
            phone
        })

        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Registo criado com sucesso' })
    }
}

export { RegisterUserController }
```